# fourier transform of real and odd symmetric signal

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

What is the fourier transform of a real and odd symmetric signal.. Is it real and non negative or just real. Some of my friends say it's imaginary and some say it's complex.. What is the answer?

Comment: I just need to know the type of the fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of a real, odd function is imaginary and odd.